# Finding the inverse of a function by swapping x with y and vice-versa

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

The professor explained the following steps were required to finding the inverse and the step was to swap x with y and y with x.

Why it is so? Well, I can follow the steps and applied it, but I couldnt understand the need for the swap.

Comment: there is no need. you can perfectly well end up with $x=(y-1)^2$ so that $f^{-1}(y) = (y-1)^2$ if you prefer. If a question asks for $f^{-1}(x)$ then you can change y to x at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because, for the `initial function`, $x$ is the *variable* (its values are represented on the abscissae axis) and $y$ is the *value* of the function (its values are represented on the ordinates axis.

For the `inverse function`, $y$ is the *variable*, so its values have to be represented on the abscissae axis, $x$ is now the *value* of the inverse function, and its values have to be represented on the ordinates axis.

A similar point of view says that, having the graph of a function (with the axes) on a sheet of paper, to see the graph of the inverse function, turn the sheet over and rotate it 90° clockwise.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in $y=\sqrt{x}+1$, $x$ is an input variable and $y$ is an output variable. The question of finding the inverse function is to make $y$ input and $x$ output variables.
For this one must rearrange the equation of the function and express $x$ in terms of $y$, that is: $x=(y-1)^2$. Then for convenience the variables are swapped to make it look like a function $y=f(x)$. However, it may not be allowed. For example, consider the cost function $C=2Q$, where $Q$ is the quantity of a good and $C$ is the cost. If a customer buys $10$ products, it will cost $20$ units of money. If a customer has $30$ units of money, he can buy at most $15$ products. So, the inverse cost function is $Q=\frac{C}{2}$. Note that swapping the variables here is meaningless.